# How to pass jQuery ajax URL value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to WordPress. I have a jQuery code like this... in my `header.php` file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#wp-submit").click(function(){  
      username=jQuery("#userName").val();
      password=jQuery("#passWord").val();
      jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>",
      data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
       success: function(html){    
      if(html=='true')    {
       jQuery("div#result").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
       jQuery("div#result").html("Login Successful");
       console.log('true');
      }
      else{
       jQuery("div#result").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
       jQuery("div#result").html("Wrong username or password");
      }

       } });
    return false;
  });
});
```

and here is the php code in the same file (header.php):

```
   <?php 
      $uName = $_POST['name'];
      $pWord = md5($_POST['pwd']);
      $results= $wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_users where user_email='".$uName."' and user_pass='".$pWord."'");
      if(count($results)==1)
      {
       echo 'true'; 
      }

      else {
        echo 'false';
      }
```

I'm not able to send request to server, i got a 404 error.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. Are you trying to access your website using `www.example.com?name=Jay&pws=kapoor`? Try adding a forward slash to it : `www.example.com/?name=Jay&pws=kapoor`. This might save you from a 404 error.

Comment: If you get a 404 error, you are able to send a request to the server. But apparently it is an invalid request.

Comment: my question was how to link php file.. i mean what url should i provide in ajax url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax url should be set to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` as ajax requests should be  handled via `wp-admin/admin-ajax` in wordpress.
if ajaxurl is not defined you can get it by defining html attribute `data-url` as `data-url="<?php echo get_admin_url().'admin-ajax.php'?>"`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $("#wp-submit").on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      username = $("#userName").val();
      password = $("#passWord").val();
      ajaxurl  = $(this).data('url');
      $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: ajaxurl,
      data : {

            name     : username,
            password : password,
            action   : 'check_user_login'

        },
       success: function(response){    
         if(response =='true')    {
             $("div#result").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
             $("div#result").html("Login Successful");
             console.log('true');
         }else{
            $("div#result").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
            $("div#result").html("Wrong username or password");
         }

       } 
    });
  });
});
```

Now Create your ajax function as

```
function user_login(){


   //do your stuff here
    global $wpdb;
    $username=$_POST['name']; 
    $password=$_POST['password']; 
    $hash = md5($password);
    $query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_email` = %s AND `user_pass` = %s", $username, $hash );
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
     if (count($result)==1) { echo 'true';
     echo '<span>Login Successful</span>'; exit(); 
    } else if(count($result) < 1) {
     echo 'false'; exit(); }
}
```

Now the ajax function should be hooked to hook
`wp_ajax_*` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_*`. Here, * is your action value i.e data.action so it becomes

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_user_login','user_login');
 add_action('wp_ajax_check_user_login','user_login');
```

Comment: Try to put this code in your funttions.php file   ini_set('display_errors', 1); and check console if any error message is displayed. that's all for today. Good luck :)

Comment: i think your sql query should have user_login instead of user_email as you are taking the username input not the email if you are using default wordpress wp_users table

Comment: can u tell me how to compare wordpress hashed password.

Comment: Go to this [link]https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password  here, go to example to see how it is to be used. Hope this works for you. I don't know what you are doing but you can use builtin login system instead of creating your own login system.